# How to install BackBee?

Tags: content-management-system

I have heard about a CMS called BackBee SymfonyLive and I would like to install it but I can not find build : can you help me?

I tried to clone the git repository but when I access the public folder I have a blank page.

Comment: What exactly do you expect as an answer to to this?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find all information you need to install BackBee in the [developper documentation](http://docs.backbee.com/developper-documentation/installation/)

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I'm part of BackBee core team*
@alexpouyat: you can find builds here => http://www.backbee.com/get-started/download-backbee

If you clone the repository, choose backbee-standard instead of BackBee which is our PHP library.

Let me know if you need help.

Comment: first, your link is dead. And now, there are 3 repo in github : backbee-cms, backbee-php and backbee-js. What should we installed ? In the video on your website, it is said to install backbee-standard. backbee-standard===backbee-cms ??

Comment: it was like 3 years ago ... I'm not working on this project anymore.